# How can I convert this dot notation to nested Objective-C brackets?

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods

I'm trying to avoid dot notation at all costs, but I am learning from a book that uses it almost explicitly, so I have been converting it out when I see it in the text. However, notation with multiple dots connected together still confuses me.

Could someone unravel these two into regular bracketed methods and explain how it works so that in the future I can convert it out on my own?

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

and

```
self.searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid dot notation? It makes code a lot readable than if you always use bracket syntax.

Comment: @yuji: That ends up being kind of a matter of opinion. :) I don't use dot syntax because I find the implied accessor calls aren't obvious and have tripped me up, so I avoid them. That's just a personal choice.

Comment: i have to partially agree with yuji and partially with quixoto :) i preffer mixed form: so that there is only one pair of brackets in the line and there is clear distinction (for old-school eyes) between the object and the message sent to it.

Comment: Its more a matter of preference, I'm new to programming in general and my only prior experience was with VB which used a lot of label1.text =  "aabbcc", so for me it just helps me keep it straight that I'm sending messages, accessing methods, and so on.. just a personal preference.. plus I came into objective c with the Big Nerd Ranch book which avoids using it and makes a pretty good (IMHO) argument for avoiding it.
http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first one would be:

```
[[self tableView] setTableHeaderView: searchBar];
```

there's also nothing wrong with using:

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView: searchBar];
```

and the second one:

```
[[self searchBar] setAutoCorrectionType: UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes];
```

here you could also use:

```
[self.searchBar setAutoCorrectionType: UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what is really going on here? Is self accessing the tableview method and setting a prop that belongs to the tableview method?

Comment: The tableview is not a method is it an object, the setTableHeaderView: is a method of the tableview object and search bar is another object you are passing as an argument to that method.

Comment: @MBarnett: actually it is (in all of this cases, including dot-only sintax) fetching tableview trough it's getter and setting searchBar trough setter. Things might get a bit mixed up when you synthesize a property using a form '@synthesize table = _table'

Comment: @Matt So self (viewDidLoad) is a view controller. Does that make it an object? If so how can it contain the object tableView? I thought objects couldn't contain other objects, just pointers to them?

Comment: @MBarnett - Yes, the view controller is a object, it is an instance of the class UIViewcontroller (or one of its subclasses). The property view is a pointer to a view (defined as UIView *view).

Comment: @MBarnett the viewDidLoad is a method of the view controller class, a view controller is an object.  And, you can think of an object as containing other objects.  I think it would be useful for you to study a brief tutorial on object oriented theory and then try and understand this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use both the getter and setter of a property with dot notation. So how to replace the for notation depends on whether you are actually using a getter (to get the value of the property) or a setter (to set the value of the property).

A getter is used like this : `value = [object myProperty];`

A setter is used like this : `[object setMyProperty:value];`

In the line:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

we are using a setter to modify the value of `tableHeaderView` in the object `self.tableView`, so it can be replaced that by:

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:searchBar];
```

Which can be replaced by: (we use a getter this time)

```
[[self tableView] setTableHeaderView:searchBar];
```

With the same reasoning, you can write:

```
[self.searchBar setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes];
```

Or:

```
[[self searchBar] setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes];
```

Comment: OK now I see my problem.. I'm tripping up on the fact that [self tableView] is one (1) object.. I was looking at it as tableView is a property of self and tableHeaderView is a property of tableView.

so if this is occurring in the -(void) viewDidLoad {} method then self is the view? or the window? Whats the difference?

Comment: **viewDidLoad()** is a method in the view controller. So **self** is the view controller which has a property **tableView**

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to "avoid dot notation at all costs"?

I'm not saying you should use dot notation, I'm just saying you should have a valid reason not to.

While we're on the topic, using dot notation for everything is clearly misuse (and if the book uses it everywhere it's technically possible, I'd say it might not be a very good book), but it's IMHO nice for getters and setters. It's nice because your code already informs the reader about what kind of method the called method is.

(so I'd say `AutomaticBobRoss.paintAnImage` is misuse because you're calling a method whose purpose is to do an operation - should be `[AutomaticBobRoss paintAnImage]` - but `AutomaticBobRoss.lastImage` is good use of dot notation)

Comment: Honestly, I think the message passing syntax is one of the most beautiful things about objective-c. Additionally, the dot notation has a dual purpose when doing iOS/Cocoa development: C Structs and OO constructs, which can be quite confusing:  [self bounds].size.width Vs self.bounds.size.width

Comment: Um I guess it just personal pref. I have to agree with the BNR guys...
http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=83

Comment: @MBarnett Well, at least you have a good book :) Use whatever syntax you're comfortable with (so long as it's not "dots everywhere I can" ;))

Comment: lol, yea highly recommend those guys, the book i'm on now is wei-meng lee's beginning ios and he uses it all over the place so.. i figure its good practice to undo all the dots when copying the examples

Comment: @Matt Yes, it is! But sometimes, the brackets get a little excessive for my taste (there isn't a need for so many brackets in Smalltalk, for instance: `AutomaticBobRoss lastImage saveToDisk.` is valid syntax; brackets are reserved for blocks. And honestly, Objective-C's block syntax is, unlike many things about it, *not* beautiful.)

Comment: @fzwo Perhaps a better distinction isn't that `-paintAnImage` is expensive, but that its main purpose is to do something other than just retrieve a property value. Use dot notation for accessing properties, but use normal message syntax for sending other kinds of messages. It'd be reasonable to use dot syntax with any accessor, even an expensive one. For example, accessing `someViewController.view` can be expensive because a .xib may have to be loaded.

Comment: @caleb you're right. I had that in a half-sentence in my original draft, but for whatever reason edited it out.